# What's the best component(s) for an interactive text box in C#?

Tags: c#

I want essentially a text box in a C# form that allows me to write to it programatically and allows the user to click in it and type text (any keyboard character), which won't appear in the text box directly, but only under my own control.  (It also needs to have a visible cursor.)  I want this for a serial port "console" pane in a form with other controls.  How can I get this functionality?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This sounds like a `TextBox` control with some weird handling in the TextChanged event. No custom library needed :)

Comment: you should just use a regular textbox and intercept the appropriate events to make this happen

Comment: You could move the input text from a text box or memo box to your control and change the text box or memo box to empty string at the same time, would be one option.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - If the text box already has a lot of text, wouldn't that require a large amount of scanning & re-scanning to find the changed text, in order to know what to send across the serial port?

Comment: You probably don't want to put everything in a single text box, you could have a list box to display received messages, and just use the text box for input, or at least have a seperate text box for input and output.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - I'm not sure if that makes sense....?  BTW, this is my very first C# program.  I'm an experienced C, C++, and assembly programmer, but have never programmed in C# before.  I hope to not be doing this long, but I need to make changes to an existing program and there is nobody at my company who has any experience in C#.  I need essentially a console "window" (text box), where characters received over the serial port appear at the end of the text box, and keys typed by the keyboard also appear, but under control of my program.  They all appear on the same line(s).

Comment: @phonetagger you may also be able to send and clear so the text box only has new data, if you want to keep a copy of send data then a list can be used to display the sent data.

Comment: I may be late but in NO WAY AT ALL is the OP asking for a recommendation of a library or tool. Putting the question on hold for this reason is totally off, to put it mildly! This is about the 10th such misguided decision I saw today. Clearly a problem you __should__ work at in MSO. But me, I will never go __THERE__ again.. Whence the negativity? Ha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a text box, make it read only, and use code like this:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "a";
        }
        //Other keys or whatever, or even some sort of foreach loop valid characters
        //However you want to handle it.
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

You could also grab catch the text changed event as others have said

Comment: Why would you not just copy the input text to the other control on a change event?